# Bootstrap button not working on android

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a website ([link](http://chaoschallenge.org)), built using Bootstrap 3. I have a button there to call for a modal window and it's not working on android (maybe on iOS as well). For desktops is fine.

Code for button is

```
<button class="btn btn-default " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">About</button>
```

Comment: What version of Android? Which browser?

Comment: @cvrebert Android 4.4.2, Opera mini and Chrome

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't support Android Opera: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support

Comment: @cvrebert, well, Chrome is shown as supported and experiences the same problem.

Comment: Your site doesn't work on iOS Safari either.

Answer (score 0):

Your site has some JS errors in Chrome. Try fixing those first:

```
HTML:<script>:65: Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined in
    FB.ui({
chaos.js:152: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined
```

Comment: I'll check this out. Strange about FB, it is given from Facebook Developers page.